# Accessing properties of PHP object like CSS-3 selector

Tags: php, css

I recently downloaded an HTML DOM parser (ganon) and noticed that it allowed accessing HTML element returned via the `file_get_dom()` function like this:

`$data = file_get_dom("someresource");`

`foreach($data('table.someClass') as $something)..`

How can I achieve this same method of accessing properties?  I've never see $var() used before.

Comment: you can go and look at the source code of the library you downloaded

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was '[variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)'.